# GV-N770OC-2GD GPU driver on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, gpu, nvidia-geforce, gpu-driver

How can I install driver for GPU (GV-N770OC-2GD) on Ubuntu (Ubuntu 16.04.1).
Gigabyte site does not show any driver for Linux OS (Ubuntu).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [Gigabyte GV-N770OC-2GD](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4629#ov) graphics card is

*Powered by **NVIDIA GeForce® GTX 770** GPU* (this is what matters when searching for drivers, the chipset).

According to Nvidia, the GTX770 should work with the following drivers versions: 352, 361, 367 and 370 (currently beta).
Open System Settings > Software & Updates and then the Additional Drivers tab -or- search "Additional Drivers" in the Dash. Select an apply the recommended proprietary driver.

Note: Adding the [Graphics Drivers PPA](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) to Ubuntu 14.04 is required to install newer drivers versions but the version already available at the 14.04 (trusty) repositories should support your card.